# Can a gerund immediately follow a present participle?

Tags: grammaticality, gerunds, present-participles, ing, gerunds-vs-participles

For example:

“Academic integrity violations include any action involving distributing course materials to others.”

I understand “involving” to be a present participle, because it functions as an adjective describing “action.” But “distributing” seems to be a gerund in that it is the subject of the verb “involving.” Is that correct, or is “distributing” something else entirely?

I understand this may just be awkward phrasing (and could be fixed by changing “distributing” to the noun “distribution”), but this example is adapted from a real-world usage of this phrasing.

Comment: Can't you parse it? What's the specific "rule" that you think is being "broken" here, and where did you read or hear of that "rule"?

Comment: It does sound funny, doesn't it? This is the [Doubl-_ing_ constraint](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4177686).

Comment: "I am planning golfing". I think the naturalness depends on how nouny the ING-form is.

Comment: If the marked duplicate does not answer your question, please elaborate.

Comment: I suspect you're thinking of the so-called 'doubl-_ing constraint_'.